# Example of adding STL iterator support to custom collection class

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, collections

I'm trying to create an example of a custom collection with an API meeting the requirements of STL iterator templates, as a learning experience.

The collection used here, a ring buffer, is merely a toy in order to help me learn the concepts involved. Once I have a better understanding of those concepts, I intend to retro-fit a similar API to a series of custom collection classes in an existing large body of code.

```
/**
 * Name        : RingQueue.cpp
 * Author      : Some Guy
 * Version     :
 * Copyright   : Copyleft 2018 Some Guy. No rights reserved.
 * Description : A ring buffer with STL iterators in C++.
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T, int capacity> class RingIter;
template <typename T, int capacity> class RingIterConst;

template <typename T, int capacity> class RingQueue {
    friend class RingIter<T, capacity>;
    friend class RingIterConst<T, capacity>;
    typedef RingIter<T, capacity> iterator;
    typedef RingIterConst<T, capacity> const_iterator;
private:
    T buf[capacity];
    int begin_idx;
    int siz;

    int end_idx() { return (begin_idx + siz) % capacity; }
public:
    RingQueue() : begin_idx(0), siz(0) {}
    ~RingQueue() {}
    int size() const { return siz; }
    T &front() {
        if (siz) {
            return buf[begin_idx];
        } else {
            throw std::invalid_argument("RingQueue is empty");
        }
    }
    const T &front() const {
        if (siz) {
            return buf[begin_idx];
        } else {
            throw std::invalid_argument("RingQueue is empty");
        }
    }
    T &back() {
        if (siz) {
            return buf[end_idx()];
        } else {
            throw std::invalid_argument("RingQueue is empty");
        }
    }
    const T &back() const {
        if (siz) {
            return buf[end_idx()];
        } else {
            throw std::invalid_argument("RingQueue is empty");
        }
    }
    T &pop_front() {
        if (!siz) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("RingQueue is empty");
        }
        T &ret = buf[begin_idx];
        begin_idx++;
        begin_idx %= capacity;
        siz--;
        return ret;
    }
    void push_back(T val) {
        buf[end_idx()] = val;
        if (siz < capacity) {
            siz++;
        } else {
            begin_idx++;
            begin_idx %= capacity;
        }
    }
    iterator begin() { return iterator(*this, 0); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(*this, siz); }
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return const_iterator(*this, 0); }
    const_iterator cend() const { return const_iterator(*this, siz); }
    iterator rbegin() { return iterator(*this, siz - 1, -1); }
    iterator rend() { return iterator(*this, -1, -1); }
    const_iterator crbegin() const { return const_iterator(*this, siz - 1, -1); }
    const_iterator crend() const { return const_iterator(*this, -1, -1); }
};

template <typename T, int capacity> class RingIterConst {
    typedef RingIterConst<T, capacity> thisclass;
protected:
    const RingQueue<T, capacity> &rq;
    int off;
    int inc;
    inline const T& deref() { return rq.buf[(rq.begin_idx + off) % capacity]; }
public:
    RingIterConst(const RingQueue<T, capacity> &iterateOver, int offset, int increment = 1) : rq(iterateOver), off(offset), inc(increment) {}
    ~RingIterConst() {}
    bool operator==(const RingIterConst &i) {
        return &i.rq == &rq && i.off == off;
    }
    bool operator!=(const RingIterConst &i) {
        return !(*this == i);
    }
    thisclass & operator++()    { off += inc; return *this; }
    thisclass & operator++(int) { off += inc; return *this; }
    thisclass & operator--()    { off -= inc; return *this; }
    thisclass & operator--(int) { off -= inc; return *this; }
    typename std::iterator_traits<thisclass>::difference_type operator-(thisclass &sibling) const { return (off - sibling.off) / inc; }
    thisclass & operator+=(int amount) { off += (amount * inc); return *this; }
    thisclass & operator-=(int amount) { off -= (amount * inc); return *this; }
    thisclass & operator-() { return thisclass(rq, off, -inc); }
    bool operator<(thisclass &sibling) const { return (inc < 0) != (off < sibling.off);}
    bool operator<=(thisclass &sibling) const { return (inc < 0) != (off <= sibling.off); }
    bool operator>(thisclass &sibling) const { return (inc < 0) != (off > sibling.off); }
    bool operator>=(thisclass &sibling) const { return (inc < 0) != (off >= sibling.off); }
    const T& operator[](int index) {
        assert(index >= 0);
        assert(index < rq.siz);
        return rq.buf[(rq.begin_idx + off + (index * inc)) % capacity];
    }
    const T& operator*() { return deref(); }
};

template <typename T, int capacity> class RingIter : public RingIterConst<T, capacity> {
public:
    RingIter(RingQueue<T, capacity> &iterateOver, int offset) : RingIterConst<T, capacity>(iterateOver, offset) {}
    ~RingIter() {}
    T& operator[](int index) { return this->rq.buf[(this->rq.begin_idx + this->off + (index * this->inc)) % this->capacity]; }
    T &operator*() { return this->deref(); }
};

// FIXME: Do not pollute namespace 'std'.
namespace std {
template<typename T, int capacity> class iterator_traits<RingIterConst<T, capacity> > {
public:
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
};
template<typename T, int capacity> class iterator_traits<RingIter<T, capacity> > : public iterator_traits<RingIterConst<T, capacity> > {
    typedef const T value_type;
    typedef const T* pointer;
    typedef const T& reference;
};
}

int main(void) {
    RingQueue<int, 4> rq;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        rq.push_back(i * i);
    }
    assert(rq.size() == 4);
    std::ostringstream s;
    std::copy(rq.cbegin(), rq.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<const int>(s, " "));
    assert(s.str() == "36 49 64 81 ");
    s.str("");
    std::copy(rq.crbegin(), rq.crend(), std::ostream_iterator<const int>(s, " "));
    assert(s.str() == "81 64 49 36 ");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Be consistent with `back()`

`end_idx()` should match either the next insertion position, or the last insertion position.  A simple test of `push_back()` and `back()` shows how these are not consistent.

This can be fixed by making `end_idx` refer to the last element added, and pre-incrementing before inserting.

## Provide `begin()`/`end()`/`rbegin()`/`rend()` for constant collections.

You want to be able to write a function like

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Capacity>
std::string to_string(const RingIter<T,Capacity>& ring)
{
    std::ostringstream s;
    std::copy(ring.begin(), ring.end(), std::ostream_iterator<const T>(s, " "));
    return s.str();
}
```

and you want to be able to write `for (auto& element: ring)` without jumping through hoops.

## Postincrement and postdecrement are wrongly implemented

`++` and `++(int)` should not be the same here (and `g++ -Weffc++` warns about this):

```
thisclass & operator++()    { off += inc; return *this; }
thisclass & operator++(int) { off += inc; return *this; }
thisclass & operator--()    { off -= inc; return *this; }
thisclass & operator--(int) { off -= inc; return *this; }
```

I'd expect

```
thisclass & operator++()    { off += inc; return *this; }
thisclass operator++(int) { auto t = *this; off += inc; return t; }
thisclass & operator--()    { off -= inc; return *this; }
thisclass operator--(int) { auto t = *this; off -= inc; return t; }
```

Of course, returning by value will involve slicing for the non-const subclass, so it will need (trivially) overloading there.

## Relational operators should not take mutable ref arguments

Instead of

```
bool operator<(thisclass &sibling) const;
```

I'd expect

```
bool operator<(thisclass const& sibling) const;
```

The same goes for the `operator-()` that takes another `thisclass`.

## Indexing operator

I've not seen an indexing operator on an iterator before, but you could simplify it just by using the programmer's expectation:

```
const T& operator[](int index) {
    return *(*this + index);
}
```

Note that the `assert()` is okay for documenting invariants, but very poor for argument checking.

## Use a `std::size_t` for sizes and indexes

Who wants a collection limited to the range of `int`?

## Iterator direction never changes

We can declare `inc` to be constant.  This doesn't affect our ability to assign values, as we already contain a reference member.

## No need to declare destructor

The iterators' destructors do nothing, so just let the compiler default them.

## Non-const iterator is completely untested

We never compile any code using the non-const version of the iterator.  Even its constructor is broken:

```
189380.cpp:83:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘RingIter<int, 4>::RingIter(RingQueue<int, 4>&, int, int)’
     iterator rbegin() { return iterator(*this, siz - 1, -1); }
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

We need to add the final argument

```
RingIter(RingQueue<T, capacity> &iterateOver, int offset, int increment = 1)
    : RingIterConst<T, capacity>(iterateOver, offset, increment)
{}
```

Its `iterator_traits` members are all private, so unusable.

A cast is required in `operator*`:

```
T &operator*() { return const_cast<T&>(this->deref()); }
```

---

## Alternative implementation

Instead of keeping a reference to the container, we could more simply just keep a pointer/reference to its *buffer* in the iterator.  We need to hold the actual index (mod `capacity`) rather than the offset from the container's current endpoint, but that's not hard:

```
template <typename T, int capacity>
class RingIter
{
    T *const buf;
    int off;
    int const inc;

public:
    RingIter(T *buf, int offset, int increment = 1)
        : buf(buf), off(offset), inc(increment)
    {}
//...
};
```

We can re-use this for both `const` and non-`const` iterators like this:

```
template <typename T, int capacity>
class RingQueue
{
public:
    typedef RingIter<T, capacity> iterator;
    typedef RingIter<const T, capacity> const_iterator;

    iterator begin() { return {buf, begin_idx}; }
    iterator end() { return {buf, begin_idx + siz}; }
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return {buf, begin_idx}; }
    const_iterator cend() const { return {buf, begin_idx + siz}; }
    iterator rbegin() { return {buf, begin_idx + siz - 1, -1}; }
    iterator rend() { return {buf, begin_idx - 1, -1}; }
    const_iterator crbegin() const { return {buf, begin_idx + siz - 1, -1}; }
    const_iterator crend() const { return {buf, begin_idx - 1, -1}; }
};
```

Now the iterator doesn't need to be a `friend` (but it does need cooperation from the container, which has to give out a pointer to its internal buffer), and we have to maintain only one iterator template (which can equally well point to `const` or non-`const` type `T`).

## Consider `std::reverse_iterator`

Simplify the iterator by using `std::reverse_iterator<RingIter<...>>` to adapt your random access iterator for reverse operation, as standard library implementations do.  This means that the iterators don't need an `inc` member to indicate their direction.

---

## Full worked example

```
#include <iterator>

template <typename T, std::size_t Capacity>
class RingIter;

template <typename T, std::size_t Capacity>
class RingQueue
{
private:
    T buf[Capacity];
    std::size_t begin_idx;
    std::size_t siz;

    T& last_val() { return buf[(begin_idx + siz - 1) % Capacity]; }

public:
    using iterator = RingIter<T, Capacity>;
    using const_iterator = RingIter<const T, Capacity>;
    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

    RingQueue()
        : begin_idx(0), siz(0)
    {}

    std::size_t size() const { return siz; }
    bool empty() const { return siz; }
    T &front() { return buf[begin_idx]; }
    const T &front() const { return buf[begin_idx]; }
    T &back() { return last_val(); }
    const T &back() const { return last_val(); }

    T &pop_front() {
        T &ret = buf[begin_idx++];
        begin_idx %= Capacity;
        --siz;
        return ret;
    }
    void push_back(const T& val) {
        if (siz < Capacity) {
            ++siz;
        } else {
            ++begin_idx %= Capacity;
        }
        last_val() = val;
    }
    void push_back(T&& val) {
        if (siz < Capacity) {
            ++siz;
        } else {
            ++begin_idx %= Capacity;
        }
        last_val() = std::move(val);
    }

    iterator begin() { return { buf, begin_idx }; }
    iterator end() { return {buf, begin_idx + siz}; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return {buf, begin_idx}; }
    const_iterator end() const { return {buf, begin_idx + siz}; }
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return begin(); }
    const_iterator cend() const { return end(); }

    reverse_iterator rbegin() { return reverse_iterator{end()}; }
    reverse_iterator rend() { return reverse_iterator{begin()}; }
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const { return const_reverse_iterator{end()}; }
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const { return const_reverse_iterator{begin()}; }
    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const { return rbegin(); }
    const_reverse_iterator crend() const { return rend(); }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t Capacity>
class RingIter
{
    T *const buf;
    std::size_t off;
public:
    RingIter(T *buf, std::size_t offset)
        : buf(buf), off(offset)
    {}
    bool operator==(const RingIter &i) {
        return &i.buf == &buf && i.off == off;
    }
    bool operator!=(const RingIter &i) {
        return !(*this == i);
    }
    RingIter & operator++()    { ++off; return *this; }
    RingIter operator++(int) { auto t = *this; ++off; return t; }
    RingIter & operator--()    { --off; return *this; }
    RingIter operator--(int) { auto t = *this; --off; return t; }
    std::ptrdiff_t operator-(RingIter const& sibling) const { return off - sibling.off; }
    RingIter & operator+=(int amount) { off += amount; return *this; }
    RingIter & operator-=(int amount) { off -= amount; return *this; }
    bool operator<(RingIter const&sibling) const { return off < sibling.off;}
    bool operator<=(RingIter const&sibling) const { return off <= sibling.off; }
    bool operator>(RingIter const&sibling) const { return off > sibling.off; }
    bool operator>=(RingIter const&sibling) const { return off >= sibling.off; }
    T& operator[](int index) const { return *(*this + index); }
    T& operator*() const { return buf[off % Capacity]; }
};

namespace std {
    template<typename T, std::size_t Capacity>
    class iterator_traits<RingIter<T,Capacity> >
    {
    public:
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    };
}

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main(void) {
    RingQueue<int, 4> ring;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ring.push_back(i * i);
    }
    assert(ring.size() == 4);
    assert(ring.front() == 36);
    assert(ring.back() == 81);
    std::ostringstream s;
    std::copy(ring.cbegin(), ring.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<const int>(s, " "));
    assert(s.str() == "36 49 64 81 ");
    s.str("");
    std::copy(ring.rbegin(), ring.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<const int>(s, " "));
    assert(s.str() == "81 64 49 36 ");

    auto const& ro_ring = ring;
    s.str("");
    std::copy(ro_ring.cbegin(), ro_ring.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<const int>(s, " "));
    assert(s.str() == "36 49 64 81 ");
    s.str("");
    std::copy(ro_ring.rbegin(), ro_ring.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<const int>(s, " "));
    assert(s.str() == "81 64 49 36 ");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, these are all excellent suggestions. Should I simply accept this answer? Or should you and I commence an iterative process, whereby I incorporate your changes and you update your critique? Sorry, I am new here.

Comment: There's a good section in the [help] entitled [What should I do when someone answers my question?](/help/someone-answers) - in summary, **do not** change the code in your question.  I'd recommend waiting a few days for answers, as there are certainly review points I've missed, and accepting an answer suggests you don't need any more review.

Comment: Do you have any useful feedback regarding the use of a distinct iterator class, instead of using a primitive type such as a pointer? In this contrived example it's required, but in the "real world" case I intend to work on next, there are multiple subclasses of collection, some which can use primitive iterators and some not. Is it as simple as: use primitive types whenever possible?

Comment: Lastly, is there any way to avoid poking things into namespace 'std'?

Comment: Last two comments - use a class whenever a primitive type won't do the job (for iterators, that's almost always, except where the storage is an array).  And you *don't* avoid defining things in `namespace std` when that's the customization point at which you're expected to define it (i.e. defining `std::iterator_traits<RingIter>` is the correct thing to do).

Comment: Thanks again. FYI, I ended up with something very like your worked example, but I nested the iterator class in the ring buffer class, which gets a little additional brevity.

Answer (score 2):

#### Avoid repeating yourself

By my count you have 5 repetitions of code to assure that the collection is non-empty before doing what a function is intended to do.

I'd move that code into a single function, and have the others call it:

```
void assure_non_empty() const { 
    if (siz == 0)
        throw std::invalid_argument("RingQueue is empty");
}

const T &back() const {
    assure_non_empty();
    return buf[end_idx()];
}

const T &front() const {
    assure_non_empty();
    return buf[begin_idx];
}

// and so on
```

#### Exception choice

I'm also a bit less than certain that `std::invalid_argument` is the right exception to throw under the circumstances. You can argue that what's involved is really an invalid argument (since `this` is passed as a hidden argument to a member function), but at least to me it "feels" wrong to throw an `invalid_argument` from a function that doesn't actually take an explicit argument.

Comment: I'd just get rid of that checking entirely, and expect the user to check `empty()` or equivalent, just like the standard containers.  Don't pay for something that's not needed!

Comment: @TobySpeight: That, of course, is an entirely valid option as well (but it's not really in keeping with what I'd consider the basic spirit of this site, which at least as I see things is mostly about refactoring while maintaining the same behavior unless that behavior is *clearly* unintended). With this design, it's also trivial to define `assure_non_empty()` as a macro that does the check for a debug built, and expands to nothing in a release build.

Comment: @Toby Thanks, I now see that there's no good reason why every correct caller, who only asks for the front or back of a non-empty collection, should have to pay for a runtime check. But I also agree that such checking should be centralised if it does continue to be present. Perhaps an assertion would be appropriate in this case?

Comment: @Jerry Which is essentially what assert does... so we seem all three of us to be basically in agreement here?

Comment: @AnotherSmellyGeek: I dunno. Retrieving iterators is rarely done so often than the cost of doing a validity check first is likely to cost enough to notice. As such, i'd *tend* toward leaving them in until/unless a profiler really indicates removing them make a big difference.

Comment: @Jerry Then I feel an assertion is a decent compromise. Profiling isn't a good option in this case (though your general attitude is sound), because this is intended to be in a library, which has no control over how its iterators are used.

Comment: @AnotherSmellyGeek: Yes and no. Although you can't control how they're used, you can write code to model likely use, and get a decent idea of how much overhead the check is likely to add. For that matter, you can model so worst-case behavior as well, and see if it ever adds enough to care about.